# Listview item text truncated after itemssource change

Tags: wpf, listviewitem, truncated

I have WPF ListView and MVVM. ListView is a part of simple parent-child structure. Parent is also ListView control. When I change selected item in parent control, ItemsSource for child control is updated. If, for example, in first ItemsSource the longest text of the items contains 5 characters, after changing ItemsSource, every item's text is visible up to 5 characters (in new ItemsSource). How can I override this problem?

Code example:

```
    <ListView Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" ItemsSource="{Binding Tasks}" Width="200" Height="250" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" SelectionMode="Extended">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridView.ColumnHeaderContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                    </Style>
                </GridView.ColumnHeaderContainerStyle>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ListViewItem}}">
                <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding Mode=TwoWay, Path=IsSelected}"/>
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ListView>
```

I use BureauBlue theme but anyway, if I don't use it, I have the same problem.

Part of the code in ViewModel:

```
    private void MyViewModel_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.PropertyName == "CurrentParentItem")
        {
            if (this.CurrentParentItem != null)
            {
                this.Tasks = GetTasks();//ObservableCollection
            }
            else
            {
                this.Tasks = null;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is your ListView wide enough to accommodate longer text?

Comment: Yes, it is. When it is cut off it takes only 10% of listview width, for example.

Comment: Can you provide us the xaml for the ListView?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GridView does not recalculate width with a new data.  To reset width you can use the following

```
            foreach (GridViewColumn c in gv.Columns)
            {
                // Code below was found in GridViewColumnHeader.OnGripperDoubleClicked() event handler (using Reflector)
                // i.e. it is the same code that is executed when the gripper is double clicked
                // if (adjustAllColumns || App.StaticGabeLib.FieldDefsGrid[colNum].DispGrid)
                if (adjustAllColumns || fdGridSorted[colNum].AppliedDispGrid)
                {
                    if (double.IsNaN(c.Width))
                    {
                        c.Width = c.ActualWidth;
                    }
                    c.Width = double.NaN;
                }
            }
```